# Laravel get sql query with argument bindings

Tags: mysql, laravel

[image]

I have build a query which then will be used as subquery. So it is needed to be transfromed to sql. When I call `toSql` method it shows me such sql query

```
"select * from `product_variant_values` where 
(`option_id` = ? and `value_id` = ?)
 or (`option_id` = ? and `value_id` = ?) 
or (`option_id` = ? and `value_id` = ?)"
```

But I want so that instead of `?` signs there will be real arguments. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot obtain the SQL with the prepared values filled.
You may use [getBindings](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_getBindings) for obtaining the values and replacing it in your query.

Comment: Very helpful. I know `setBindings`, but did not think about `getBindings`. Now i can prepend bindings of subquery with main query and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

just a cheating way.

You can edit your query to get a syntax error. You can see your query with all arguments

Comment: If I needed to see the query I would use a debugger. But I need to use it as subquery with all bindings. So it is not an answer.